# UITextView showing distorted at run time in XCode 8

Tags: uitextview, ios10, xcode8

**STORYBOARD**
[image: STORYBOARD]

**Simulator/Device:** 
[image]

There are no constraints warming or error of any kind. 
Xcode 8, iOS 10

UPDATE:
I have removed the UIView and still the concave shape coming (UITextView color is set gray at run-time). Unable to judge anything from storyboard nor from constraint setup. 
[image]

**UPDATE 2** : I have found UITextView **textContainer** is messing things up and **layer.cornerRadius**  also making things worse.

Comment: if that is a textview, are you using a background image ? Are you drawing anything on textview ? Is that IBDesignable textview ?

Comment: No not a background image nor IBDesignable textview, I tried after even removing my custom class of uitextview